# Не выводит String в C# Texbox.Text (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Столкнулся с не понятной для меня проблемой. В двух случаях:

1) Не обновляется TextBox по DispatcherTimer.

```
private DispatcherTimer SetTimer(int interval)
{
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerExecutionEvent);
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, interval);
    return timer;
}

private void TimerExecutionEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)
{
    TimerExceptionBox.Text = String.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss.fff}",e.ToString()).ToString());
}
```

2) Просто не выводит текст через Text Box:

```
OutDialogText.Text = Environment.NewLine + "Sending a request...";
```

Оба события запускаются по очереди сначала 1, потом 2. По клику кнопки.

Comment: По всей видимости, вы что-то делаете тяжелое в UI потоке, потому у вас не происходит обновление данных в текстбоксах. Так что вы не там проблему ищите...

Comment: Bulson, хм возможно - это из-за того что там происходит запрос в google platform?

Comment: `...это из-за того что там происходит запрос в google platform?` вот это уже более вероятная причина. Вы, наверное, не используете `async/await`?

Comment: @Bulson. Вообще пользуюсь: 

`Task<LongRunningRecognizeResponse> task = Task.Run(() => sttg.CreateRequestAysnc(data.Client.Google, data.RecognitionConfig.Google, data.AudioConfig.Google));
            task.Wait();`

Comment: Еще, если добавить `MessageBox.Show()`, то GUI обновится.

Comment: `task.Wait();` - лочит UI, его нельзя использовать.

Comment: Спасибо! Вчера с помощью проб и ошибок добился, что бы работало. Но от реализации слезы текут, пойду переделывать сейчас. Не могу отметить коммент как решение. Напиши в ответах пожалуйста, я отмечу.

Comment: А мне писать нечего, я же не дал ответ, а только подсказал. Так что напиши ответ на свой же вопрос сам. Что мол дело было совсем не в том, что предполагалось, а в неправильной работе с Task. Что была такая-то реализация, а стала такая и все исправилось. Другим может пригодится.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо! Очень помог на самом деле!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело оказало не в TextBox.Text, а в том что метод Task.Wait блокировал UI-поток. Для решения я заменил Wait на await. Еще метод который я вызывал вот так:

```
Task<LongRunningRecognizeResponse> task  = Task.Run(() => sttg.CreateRequestAysnc(data.Client.Google, data.RecognitionConfig.Google, data.AudioConfig.Google))
```

Не требовал постановки в очередь для запуска в пуле потоков, по этому можно убрать `Task.Run` и изменить тип принимающей переменной с `Task<LongRunningRecognizeResponse>` на `LongRunningRecognizeResponse`. А так же при вызове метода добавить await.

Как было:

```
Task<LongRunningRecognizeResponse> task = Task.Run(() => sttg.CreateRequestAysnc(data.Client.Google, data.RecognitionConfig.Google, data.AudioConfig.Google));
task.Wait();
```

Как стало:

```
LongRunningRecognizeResponse response = await sttg.CreateRequestAysnc(data.Client.Google, data.RecognitionConfig.Google, data.AudioConfig.Google);
```

После этого Ui-поток разлочился. И таймер спокойно тикал в TextBox.

***Отдельное большое спасибо Bulson.***